# Prediction for non-negative data using PLS/alternative

Tags: machine-learning, caret

I am currently using PLS (the set of predictors are quite highly-dimensional) to predict a particular variable, $age$, and I am using Caret's *train* implementation using the *pls* method:

```
modelFit <- train(train$age~.,data=train,method = "pls",tuneLength=100)
```

The above method does pretty well at predicting, although it does sometimes predict a negative value for $age$, which is nonsensical.

To try to sort this problem, I have tried using $log(age)$ as my dependent variable, then exponentiating to retrieve a non-negative value of $age$. This seems to do ok, but the model does (predictably) exhibit considerable heteroscedasticity, where the error variance increases with $age$. This is because I am training a model on the log scale, and hence a prediction that does reasonably well on this scale will not on the non-logged scale.

I am not sure whether this method is optimal; I can't help but think that training on the logged scale, when what I care about is on the non-logged scale is not idea. In particular, are there any machine learning methods that account for this type of dependent variable naturally? Are these preferential?

**Edit:** to be clear, I know of models that handle this problem (such as the **Tobit** model) in econometrics. What I am after here is whether there are machine learning equivalents that handle this. Essentially, are there modifications to *PLS* or other dimensionality-reduction techniques that prevent non-negative predictions?

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `predictionBounds` option in `trainControl`. You can set a lower (or upper) limit on what the predictions can be

Max

Answer (score 0):

Could the tobit model be what you are looking for?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model

Comment: Hi, I know the Tobit model, but I don't know whether there are implementations of this with PLS/other-machine-learning-packages. I am looking for this type of information here.